# NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass on user creation rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, mongoid

When I run my rails 5.1 app in development, everything is fine but when I run it on Heroku and try to create a user I keep getting this error.

```
    NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/mongo-2.5.3/lib/mongo/cluster.rb:192:in `initialize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/mongo-2.5.3/lib/mongo/client.rb:454:in `new'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/mongo-2.5.3/lib/mongo/client.rb:454:in `create_from_addresses'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/mongo-2.5.3/lib/mongo/client.rb:253:in `initialize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/mongoid-7.0.1/lib/mongoid/clients/factory.rb:64:in `new'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/mongoid-7.0.1/lib/mongoid/clients/factory.rb:64:in `create_client'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/mongoid-7.0.1/lib/mongoid/clients/factory.rb:27:in `create'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/mongoid-7.0.1/lib/mongoid/clients.rb:69:in `block in with_name'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/mongoid-7.0.1/lib/mongoid/clients.rb:68:in `synchronize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/mongoid-7.0.1/lib/mongoid/clients.rb:68:in `with_name'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/mongoid-7.0.1/lib/mongoid/persistence_context.rb:110:in `client'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/mongoid-7.0.1/lib/mongoid/persistence_context.rb:70:in `collection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/mongoid-7.0.1/lib/mongoid/clients/options.rb:73:in `collection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/mongoid-7.0.1/lib/mongoid/contextual/mongo.rb:342:in `initialize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/mongoid-7.0.1/lib/mongoid/contextual.rb:53:in `new'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/mongoid-7.0.1/lib/mongoid/contextual.rb:53:in `create_context'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/mongoid-7.0.1/lib/mongoid/contextual.rb:35:in `context'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/mongoid-7.0.1/lib/mongoid/contextual.rb:20:in `exists?'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/mongoid-7.0.1/lib/mongoid/validatable/uniqueness.rb:276:in `validate_root'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/mongoid-7.0.1/lib/mongoid/validatable/uniqueness.rb:48:in `block in validate_each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/mongoid-7.0.1/lib/mongoid/validatable/queryable.rb:23:in `with_query'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/mongoid-7.0.1/lib/mongoid/validatable/uniqueness.rb:42:in `validate_each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activemodel-5.1.0/lib/active_model/validator.rb:150:in `block in validate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activemodel-5.1.0/lib/active_model/validator.rb:147:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activemodel-5.1.0/lib/active_model/validator.rb:147:in `validate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:413:in `block in make_lambda'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:178:in `block (2 levels) in halting_and_conditional'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:601:in `block (2 levels) in default_terminator'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:600:in `catch'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:600:in `block in default_terminator'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:179:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:507:in `block in invoke_before'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:507:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:507:in `invoke_before'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:130:in `run_callbacks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/mongoid-7.0.1/lib/mongoid/interceptable.rb:132:in `run_callbacks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:825:in `_run_validate_callbacks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activemodel-5.1.0/lib/active_model/validations.rb:405:in `run_validations!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activemodel-5.1.0/lib/active_model/validations/callbacks.rb:110:in `block in run_validations!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:131:in `run_callbacks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/mongoid-7.0.1/lib/mongoid/interceptable.rb:132:in `run_callbacks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:825:in `_run_validation_callbacks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activemodel-5.1.0/lib/active_model/validations/callbacks.rb:110:in `run_validations!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activemodel-5.1.0/lib/active_model/validations.rb:335:in `valid?'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/mongoid-7.0.1/lib/mongoid/validatable.rb:97:in `valid?'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activemodel-5.1.0/lib/active_model/validations.rb:372:in `invalid?'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/mongoid-7.0.1/lib/mongoid/persistable/creatable.rb:117:in `prepare_insert'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/mongoid-7.0.1/lib/mongoid/persistable/creatable.rb:23:in `insert'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/mongoid-7.0.1/lib/mongoid/persistable/savable.rb:23:in `save'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/mongoid-7.0.1/lib/mongoid/persistable/savable.rb:44:in `save!'
/app/db/seeds.rb:15:in `block in <top (required)>'
/app/db/seeds.rb:4:in `times'
/app/db/seeds.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `block in load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/mongoid-7.0.1/lib/mongoid/railties/database.rake:20:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `kernel_load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:27:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/cli.rb:360:in `exec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:369:in `dispatch'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/cli.rb:20:in `dispatch'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:444:in `start'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/cli.rb:10:in `start'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/exe/bundle:30:in `block in <top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:121:in `with_friendly_errors'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/exe/bundle:22:in `<top (required)>'
/app/bin/bundle:3:in `load'
/app/bin/bundle:3:in `<main>'
```

I can't place what could be causing the error. It is running a DB on mongoid in mlab. Not sure if that is the cause. I can't seed the db in heroku console without getting the same error.

Comment: check the 64 line in factory.rb , you are calling each method for nil class. please add the code of line no 64 in question

Comment: @Vishal Please explain...I dont have a factory.rb file? Please explain where are you seeing this?

Comment: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/mongoid-7.0.1/lib/mongoid/clients/factory.rb:64:in `new'..... do you have cluster.rb file ? Please add full log in question its unclear

Comment: I dont have a cluster.rb file

Comment: Error is in your seeds.rb file , please check line 4 and 15 in you seeds.rb .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180642/discussion-between-supremea-and-vishal).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the Mongo driver is expecting to iterate across a number of host URIs, but has somehow managed to reach that point in the code without detecting that there aren't any defined.

As you're using Mongoid to interact with the (slight lower level) Mongo Ruby client, this [file on configuration](https://github.com/mongodb/mongoid/blob/master/docs/tutorials/mongoid-configuration.txt) might give you some clues. You'll probably want to also refer to the documentation for whichever MongoDB add-on you have installed on Heroku.

Comment: You are correct it was an incorrect configuration in my mongoid.yml file. Thanks!